# Error when calling the service in async mode

Tags: wcf, idictionary, asynchronous-wcf-call

Stackoverflow is definetly the fastest forum so after posting this question in the WCF forum I decided to come here.

I have a wcf service which returns a dictionary (IDictionary) and that works just fine. Now I wanted to add the capability of calling that service in async mode, but when the BeginMethod gets executed I get the following Exception:

> The type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[TransferProp,
>   Contracts, Version=10.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa]] is
>   not supported because it implements
>   IDictionary.

What's up with that?

Comment: Please post the complete exception, along with any InnerException. Post the output of ex.ToString().

Comment: this is the innerexception, the outter was just 'could not ptoccess argument'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This (CodeIdol) blog](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Data-Contracts/Collections/) talks about deriving your own [CollectionDataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) collection and returning this. Does this help?

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<int,Contact>
{}

[ServiceContract]
interface IContactManager
{
   ...
   [OperationContract]
   MyDictionary GetContacts( );
}
```

Comment: it did not help, but that's the way one is suppose to do it, so I mark as answered. Found the same resolution from many resources, don't know what my problrm is :(